# Warnings in R glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

Tags: r, glm

I run logistic models in 4 strata because of effect modification. In one of these strata, there occured the following warning:

> glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred.

By using the summary() function, I saw that the model fits the data and the model converged and estimates were calculated. As I wanted to prestent Odds Ratio, I used the function tab_model. It was not possible to calculate both the OR and the CI.
(I only used binary variables.)

My code used:

```r
model.1f <- glm(over ~ as.factor(parent_prim_bin) + age,
                data = data, family  ="binomial")
```

`over` means overweight (low/high);
`parent_prim_bin` means primary education (low/high);
`age` means age (metric)

Do you have any ideas to solve this problem?

Comment: Won't treating "over" with as.factor help?

Comment: Unfortunately, this warning still occurs - namely 29 time.

Comment: The error is indicating a clear step function in the probabilities. At one side of your data everything is True and then at some value everything becomes False. For example, maybe your data shows low over weight for everyone with low education and vice verse.   Try your model without the `as.factor(parent_prim_bin)` term to see what happens. Without seeing your data is difficult to provide a meaningful answer.

Comment: Yes, everyone who has overweight has low education, but in the group of people having no overweight there is a little bit more variance in the data. Solution could be to extend the sample size or to recode the variables?

Comment: If "everyone who has overweight has low education" is True. So all the high education have no overweight, thus the source of the error.  You need to remove all of the high education individuals and rerun the model.  Regression with factors is basically a series of individual regressions for each factor.    Thus when you have a factor with 100% correlation to response you need to change the model.